# Excel - how to get sumproduct of adjacent cells in one row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row of values and want to get the product of the first pair, the product of the second pair and so on, then sum the products.

For example, for:
5 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 6

I would expect the result to be 78 (50 + 10 + 18)

This formula achieves the correct result:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(C19:V19)-COLUMN(C19)+1,2)=0),C19:V19,--(MOD(COLUMN(B19:U19)-COLUMN(B19)+1,2)=0),B19:U19)`

However I can't stager the ranges like that (C19:V19 and B19:U19). I need to only use C19:V19 (which is where the actual data is) in the formula. It's just staggered here so that the second part of the formula picks up the odd cells and the first part picks up the evens.

I need to figure out an equivalent forumula that just uses C19:V19.

As part of that attempt I've reach this point:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(C19:V19)-COLUMN(C19)+1,2)=0)*C19:V19,--(MOD(COLUMN(C19:V19)-COLUMN(C19)+1,2)=1)*C19:V19)
```

Which would correctly pick up the odds and evens, but will always multiply each product out to 0.

I'm struggling to come up with another method. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works : `=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(C1:H1;0;1)*(C1:H1);--(MOD(COLUMN(C1:H1)-COLUMN(C1);2)=0))`

The `OFFSET` shifts your array one position to the right, then you multiply with the original array, and then you have to only sum the uneven positions, which is done with the `SUMPRODUCT` and the array you create with the `--MOD()`

I just used the 6 numbers you put in your question in C1:H1, so you have to change this reference with C19:V19.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that! Just a note that excel throws an error for me unless I change the semicolons to commas. Possibly down to a syntax difference between versions?

Comment: Yes indeed, I always forget to mention that. This depends on your regional settings and the list separator you choose there. By default this is linked to the decimal symbol : if this is comma (as in most European countries), the list separator is semicolon, if it is a decimal point (as in the US), the list separator is comma.